# Push element in STL vector but not found when using 'at'

Tags: vector, stl, c++98

I am trying to do something REALLY simple, add an integer to a vector and remove it.  But when I use `at` to determine if the element was inserted, exception is thrown.

```
class Obj
{
    ...
private:
    std::vector<unsigned int> elements;
}

void Obj::addElement(unsigned int elt)
{
    elements.push_back(elt);
    printElements();
}

void Obj::removeElement(unsigned int elt)
{
    try
    {
        printElements();
        elements.at(elt);
    }
    catch (const exception& ex)
    {
        cout << "NOT FOUND" << endl;
        return;
    }
    elements.erase(std::remove(elements.begin(), elements.end(), elt, elements.end());
}       

void Obj::printElements()
{
    for(vector<unsigned int>::iterator i = elements.begin(); i != elements.end();++i)
    {
        cout << *i << endl;
    }
}
```

Passing in `5` let's say...
    obj.addElement(5);
    obj.removeElement(5);

`printElements` always prints what you'd expect. But in `removeElement` an exception is always thrown and `5` is never removed.

Not sure why this simple usage wouldn't work.

Comment: `at` wants an index.

Answer (score 1):

"At" expects to receive the element's position and not it's actual value.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at

Comment: It happens to the best of us.